# Getting custom attribute value from simple product load based on product collection

Tags: attributes, collection, simple-product, dropdown-attribute

I have built a collection (includes `->addAttributeToSelect('*')`) to generate a CSV and then from this collection, I need to fetch the associated simple products so that I can load different sizes, colours etc:-

```
$associatedProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product);
```

And I can then load each simple product in a `foreach` loop:-

```
foreach ($associatedProducts as $simple) {
        //load product
        $simple_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($simple->getId());
}
```

I have a custom attribute (dropdown) and I need to only load simple products if this dropdown value is set to 'Yes' but I can only seem to be able to fetch this value for a configurable product:-

```
$product->getAttributeText('attribute_code'); <-- this works
```

Trying to get the attribute from the simple product doesn't work:-

```
$simple->getAttributeText('attribute_code'); <-- this doesn't work
```

And it returns `bool(false)` rather than a string.

There is obviously lots more of this script but I am hoping I have just pulled out what is relevant above.

Can anyone shed any light as to what I need to do differently for me to get the attribute value from the simple product loading?

### Edit

Here is a sample SQL output for one of the simple products as per the comments in @Richard's answer below:-

```
SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`cost`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`gift_message_available`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`is_recurring`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_title`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`sku_type`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`url_path`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`product_teaser`, `e`.`manufacturer`, `e`.`manufacturer_value`, `e`.`product_size_women`, `e`.`product_size_women_value`, `e`.`image`, `e`.`colour`, `e`.`colour_value` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.category_id = '3' WHERE (e.type_id = 'configurable') AND (e.visibility IN(4, 3, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the prototype for `getUsedProducts`? It's `public function getUsedProducts($requiredAttributeIds = null, $product = null)` so you can call `getUsedProducts(array(id_of_your_attribute), $product)`

Looping through that array and then loading each child is probably not the most efficient way of doing what you're after. You could either add the other attributes you need to the getUsedProducts, or if there's lots and adding by `id` doesn't make sense, just use `getUsedProductCollection` and add call `addAttributeToSelect` or `addAttributeToFilter` yourself, see what `getUsedProducts` does itself:

```
if (is_array($requiredAttributeIds)) {
    foreach ($requiredAttributeIds as $attributeId) {
        $attribute = $this->getAttributeById($attributeId, $product);
        if (!is_null($attribute))
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute->getAttributeCode(), array('notnull'=>1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Useful information, thanks @Richard. I posted a [follow up question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/78495/798) though as I learned that I am able to get another custom attribute but not this one with the same code.

Comment: You could probably have just edited this question. Did you notice it was attribute_id not attribute_code? you might want to debug what sql is getting generated for the collection

Comment: I did think about editing it but wasn't sure if there was slightly different... In the array for `getUsedProducts` I tried with the ID of the attributes but it makes no difference. I've already var dumped every simple product but I guess I could try and see if I can figure anything out from the SQL generated - thanks.

Comment: Can't even get `getSelect` to work (like `echo $simple_product->getSelect();`). This is a script located in the Magento root to generate a CSV.

Comment: `getSelect()` is called on the collection, which is where `$simple_product`  is being loaded from because you're calling `->getAttributeText` before (if you are still) loading the whole object. You want to see if you're successfully getting it to request the attribute you want

Comment: Sorry Richard, I had tried it on the collection and it wasn't working but I retried, trimming the `getSelect` right back and now it is working, I have posted the SQL output for one of the simple products in the question which I think proves what we already knew (?) that the attribute I want isn't being loaded hence why it isn't working? Thanks

Comment: Oh, you're using the flat product table, so you need to make sure that the attribute has `used in product listing` set in `catalog/attributes/manage attributes`

Comment: Haha. Yes, I already tried setting that :) even with this problem (will retry now though).

Comment: Hmm, no joy with the attribute set to 'Used in product listing'. Reindexed and cache flushed. This works `var_dump($simple->getAttributeText('product_size_women'));` and this doesn't `var_dump ($simple->getAttributeText('attribute_code'));`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26892/discussion-between-zigojacko-and-richard).

Comment: Actually, the attribute I need is appearing in the SQL output now. Still not able to get the value though :/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's a hack or the normal way, but you can get the attribute id using

```
$attrId = $simple->getResource()
    ->getAttributeRawValue($simple->getId(), 'attribute_name', 0);
```

and the text using

```
$simple->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_name')
    ->getSource()->getOptionText($attrId)
```