# Can't get custom attribute from getUsedProducts

Tags: product-attribute, collection

This follows on from [my previous question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78459/getting-custom-attribute-value-from-simple-product-load-based-on-product-collect/78462#78462).

I am getting all the child products of it's parents by using the following:-

```
$associatedProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null, $product);
```

I am already fetching values from custom attributes (dropdowns) in simple products using the following:-

```
$sizing = $simple->getAttributeText('product_size_women');
```

This works fine, I am able to get the size value for each simple product but this attribute is set as 'Use To Create Configurable Product'.

I cannot fetch the values from a different custom attribute (also a dropdown) that isn't used to create a configurable product though and I suspect this has something to do with how `getUsedProducts` functions.

I have tried loading the attribute id into an array like below but this has no affect probably because attributes that aren't used to create a configurable cannot be retrieved in this function - I'm unsure.

```
getUsedProducts(array(id_of_your_attribute), $product)
```

I'd simply like to get the value of the custom attribute in the same way as I am getting the sizing ones above:-

```
$sendtofeed = $simple->getAttributeText('attribute_code'));
```

Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's a hack or the normal way, but you can get the attribute id using

```
$sizeId = $simple->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($simple->getId(), 'product_size_women', 0);
```

and the text using

```
$simple->getResource()->getAttribute('product_size_women')->getSource()->getOptionText($sizeId)
```